# Cache Thrashing effect decreases for big data size

Tags: algorithm, memory, memory-management

I can observe the effect of cache thrashing when I apply simple algorithms (matrix multiplication, LU factorization, etc) on matrices of size 2^n: basically, there are time peaks at matrix sizes 2^k. For growing values of 2^n though, this phenomenon does not verify anymore (say size = 2^14x2^14 = 16384x16384).
What is this due to?

***Edit***
Running some very simple experiments in matlab, I get the following:

```
>> n = 1024;  
>> AA = rand(n);
>> tic; lu(AA); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.163291 seconds.
>> n = 1025;
>> AA = rand(n);
>> tic; lu(AA); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.040935 seconds.
```

And again going to the next power of 2, cache thrashing is verified but less evidently:

```
>> n = 4096;
>> AA = rand(n);
>> tic; lu(AA); toc;
Elapsed time is 1.208170 seconds.
>> n = 4097;
>> AA = rand(n);
>> tic; lu(AA); toc;
Elapsed time is 1.120656 seconds.
```

On this laptop, cache thrashing doesn't verify anymore for matrix size = 2^13x2^13:

```
>> n = 8192;
>> AA = rand(n);
>> tic; lu(AA); toc
Elapsed time is 8.586088 seconds.
>> n = 8193;
>> AA = rand(n);
>> tic; lu(AA); toc;
Elapsed time is 8.676817 seconds.
```

(I know these are random matrices and that the time difference is small, but I have observed this trend running many experiments).
Same thing for C implementation.

Comment: Hard to tell if we don't know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: I read (long ago, can't find it anymore, unfortunately), that cache thrashing doesn't verify when data size is very big. Maybe because when data is so big that the cache is filled anyway, then the frequent loading and unloading of the same cache lines caused by the addressing procedure (that is basically what cache thrashing is about) doesn't occur anymore, and so these time peaks at data size 2^n are no more there (?). Anyway, I edited my question by adding some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three reasons for cache misses (the 3C): compulsory (when a data has not been loaded in a cache line), conflict (when the cache maps data to an already occupied line whilst some free space exist in the cache) and capacity (when all the cache is full).

Mapping data in cache relies on power of two decomposition of the address and explains why matrices whose size is 2^k will have their lines mapped to identical cache blocks, leading to conflict misses. Present computers try to overcome this problem with high associativity caches, but it still happens. Using a not power of two matrix size is a way to spread the matrix the matrix in all cache blocks and to avoid this problem.

When the matrix size is increased, we will encounter capacity misses. If your matrix do not fit in the cache, ejecting lines to read new lines will be required whether the size of your matrix is or not a power of two. This is the reason, you have similar slow down whatever the matrix size over a certain threshold.

For lu decomposition, you will need to process some n^2 matrices. If the algorithm is well written, storing a single mat in he cache can lead to some performance improvements. But, if your matrix are 8kx8k, each matrix is 512MB, which is far beyond the size of caches in present computers. This is also exactly the same situation with 4k matrices (128MB), and the slight difference that you see in your bench mark is not significant. Because optimizations in present computer are somehow statistical, running the *same* program several times currently leads to at least 10-20% differences in the run time.

For a 1k matrix, the situation is different. It just require 8M storage, which is the size of the L3 cache in recent pentium microarchitecture. Most misses will be due to conflict and not to capacity and the cache trashing effect of 2^k matrices happens.

Just a final remark. You should not do benchmarks while just using rand(). This way rand is not seeded and your data will effectively be random. But the execution time of numerical algorithms is somehow dependent on data value and this will break the accuracy of your benchmark. Use rng(seed) before to always have the same sequence and do several tests.